# Can I use step functions to check whether a lambda is running to allow only one instance of lambda running to avoid db deadlock?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, concurrency, aws-step-functions, database-deadlocks

I have a state machine which gets triggered every time a file is uploaded to S3.
This state machine is triggered by a lambda which is connected to SQS and is invoked on every file upload.
For one of the processes, thi step machine contains a function which writes to a database.
I dont have a problem with multiple instances os state machines running parallely but this 2nd lambda function in the state machine which writes to the db should not run parallely to avoid table deadlock.
Is there a way I can get the state of lambda using the step functions and execute it only when it is not running by any other instance of step functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit an AWS Lambda function so that it only runs **a maximum of one instance** of the function at any time, then you can **set the Reserved Concurrency to 1**.

See: [Managing Lambda reserved concurrency - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
However I dont want to fail the second invocation of lambda function which will happen in case of setting concurrency =1. Instead I want to run all the invocations serially.

Comment: The second (and other) Lambda functions will effectively queue for their chance to run. From [Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/): _"If the function uses reserved concurrency, this acts as a maximum capacity, so the internal queue retains the messages until the function can process them."_ Have you seen documentation that suggests they would fail instead?

Comment: HI John , I dont think any internal queue comes into picture as my second instance of lambda function got failed with
" Lambda.TooManyRequestsException
Rate Exceeded. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 429, Request ID: xxxxxxxxxxx)"

However you are right, this behaviour contradicts with the documentation.Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: You could fix it by sending a message to an Amazon SQS queue and then configuring that queue as a trigger to the Lambda function. SQS will definitely 'queue up' the messages for delivery to the Lambda function.